# Get hardware type in Unified API

Tags: ios, xamarin

How do I get the device hardware type in Unified API?  [Here's an example of how to do it in Classic API.](http://pastebin.com/FJfpGRbQ).  In that example, the "[DllImport(Constants.SystemLibrary)]" part doesn't compile.  It seems that has changed in Unified API?

---

So this is the old Classic code.  How do I do this in Unified after including "ObjCRuntime"?

```
    [DllImport(MonoTouch.Constants.SystemLibrary)]
    static internal extern int sysctlbyname([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string property, IntPtr output, IntPtr oldLen, IntPtr newp, uint newlen);

    public DeviceHardware ()
    {
        var pStr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
        sysctlbyname(HardwareProperty, pStr, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

        string DeviceTypeString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pStr);
    }
```

---

Solution below.  I had to use "ObjCRuntime" instead of "MonoTouch"

```
[DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.SystemLibrary)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Constants` class is in the ObjCRuntime namespace, so you just need to add this `using` clause at the top of the file:

```
using ObjCRuntime;
```

Comment: So the classic method was getting hardware properties from the extern method "sysctlbyname".  How do I access that with the new method from ObjCRuntime?  Thanks in advance (I added the method up top)